# C sockets - Blocked on select

Tags: c, sockets, select-function

I am working on a client server program , that uses select() calls to listen to multiple sockets. But my select call gets blocked, although I have a message in one of those sockets , select() call doesn't recognize it and it's still waits there indefinetly.

There are 2 entities in the program , a master and a client. 
The master knows the number of clients it will handle and waits for the clients to connect to it. Once it receives a client acknowledgement, it stores its information. Once all the clients are connected, it then sends its neighboring client's information to every client so it can form a network. It is here, I use the select() to monitor many sockets,
master has a socket to every child tat is connected to it
client has 3 main sockets
s1-to speak with master
s2-child listens for connection on this socket
neighbour-the socket on which its neighbour wait for a connection.(i.e S2 in a neighbour)
p- the socket that is results of connection from its neighbour ( accept of s2 - returns ths)
I use select to listen to server, its own socket for incoming connections and once.

Initially my server sends a string "hello" to one of the client, which receives this message and passes it on to the neighbour, in this way when the string reaches back to the first child that has received this message from server , it passes it on to its neighbour. But all  though all child are in select() waiting for an input. What could cause this ??

```
void main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int s1, s2, n, server_port, sc1, sc2, rv, rc, left_peer_port;
    int peer_port;
    fd_set writefds, readfds;
    struct timeval tv;
    struct hostent *server_info, *child_info, *left_peer_info;
    int start_flag = 0;

    struct sockaddr_in server, peer, incoming;

    char host_child[64];
    char *left_host = malloc(1);
    char *right_host = malloc(1);
    char buf1[256];
    char buf2[256];

    server_port = atoi(argv[2]);

    //speak to peer using this
    s2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s2 < 0) {
        perror("socket:");
        exit(s2);
    }

    peer_port = server_port + 1;

    gethostname(host_child, sizeof host_child);

    child_info = gethostbyname(host_child);

    if (child_info == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: host not found (%s)\n", argv[0], host_child);
        exit(1);
    }


    peer.sin_family = AF_INET;
    memcpy(&peer.sin_addr, child_info->h_addr_list[0], child_info->h_length);
    int changeport = 0;
    do {
        peer.sin_port = htons(peer_port);
        rc = bind(s2, (struct sockaddr *) &peer, sizeof(peer));

        if (rc < 0) {
            //perror("bind:");
            peer_port++;
            changeport = 1;
            //exit(rc);

        } else {
            changeport = 0;
        }

    } while (changeport == 1);

    if (listen(s2, 100) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(3);
    }



//Now talk to server

    server_info = gethostbyname(argv[1]);

    if (server_info == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: host not found\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }


// pretend we've connected both to a server at this point
//speak to server using this
    s1 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (s1 < 0) {
        perror("socket:");
        exit(s1);
    }


    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(server_port);
    memcpy(&server.sin_addr, server_info->h_addr_list[0], server_info->h_length);

//To talk to the server

    sc1 = connect(s1, (struct sockaddr *) &server, sizeof(server));
    if (sc1 < 0) {
        perror("connect:");
        exit(sc1);
    }

    int send_len;
    char *str = malloc(1);
    sprintf(str, "%d", peer_port);
    printf("\nport-here=%s\n", str);


    send_len = send(s1, str, strlen(str), 0);
    if (send_len != strlen(str)) {
        perror("send");
        exit(1);
    }

    int recv_len;
    char buf[100];
    int ref = 0;
    int recv_stage = 0;
    int start_id;


    recv_len = recv(s1, buf, 34, 0);
    if (recv_len < 0) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }
    buf[recv_len] = '\0';
    char *temp_port;

    if (!strcmp("close", buf))
        printf("%s", buf);
            //break;
    else {
        char *temp_buffer = malloc(1);
        char *id = malloc(100);
        char *pp = malloc(1);
        strcpy(temp_buffer, buf);

        char *search = ":";
        temp_port = strtok(temp_buffer, search);
        strcpy(buf, temp_port);
        printf("temp_name%s", temp_port);

        temp_port = strtok(NULL, search);
        strcpy(pp, temp_port);
        printf("temp_port%s", temp_port);
        temp_port = strtok(NULL, search);
        strcpy(id, temp_port);
        printf("id%s", temp_port);

        strcpy(temp_port, pp);
        printf("\nbuf=%s\n", buf);
        printf("\nport=%s\n", temp_port);
        printf("\nid=%s\n", id);
        start_id = atoi(id);
    }

//To send packet to its neighbour
    left_peer_info = gethostbyname(buf);
    printf("\nleft host=%s\n", buf);
    if (left_peer_info == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: host not found\n", left_host);
        exit(1);
    }
    left_peer_port = atoi(temp_port);


    int neighbour_socket;
    struct hostent *neighbour_info;
    struct sockaddr_in neighbour;
    neighbour_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (neighbour_socket < 0) {
        perror("socket:");
        exit(neighbour_socket);
    }

    neighbour_info = left_peer_info;


    neighbour.sin_family = AF_INET;
    neighbour.sin_port = htons(left_peer_port);
    memcpy(&neighbour.sin_addr, neighbour_info->h_addr_list[0], neighbour_info->h_length);

    printf("\nconnected to port %d\n", left_peer_port);
    //To talk to the neighbour
    printf("\ncomes here\n");


//Listen on this socket connection for potato

    int send_peer_len;
    int nfds;

    nfds = MAX(MAX(neighbour_socket, s2), s1);

// clear the set ahead of time
    FD_ZERO(&writefds);

// add our descriptors to the set
    FD_SET(neighbour_socket, &writefds);
    FD_SET(s1, &writefds);
    FD_SET(s2, &writefds);

//FD_SET(s2, &writefds);


    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(neighbour_socket, &readfds);
    FD_SET(s1, &readfds);
    FD_SET(s2, &readfds);

//select()

// since we got s2 second, it's the "greater", so we use that for
// the n param in select()
//n = s1 + 1;

// wait until either socket has data ready to be recv()d (timeout 10.5 secs)
    tv.tv_sec = 10;
    tv.tv_usec = 500000;

    int fds[3];
    fds[0] = s1;
    fds[1] = s2;
    fds[2] = neighbour_socket;
    int p = 0;
    int p_flag = 0;

    while (1) {
        printf("\n nfds = %d , p = %d \n", nfds, p);
        char buf_msg[64];


        //This is where the error occurs  //

        rv = select(nfds, &readfds, NULL, NULL, 0);

        //This is where the error occurs  //

        if (rv == -1) {
            perror("select"); // error occurred in select()
        } else if (rv == 0) {
            printf("Timeout occurred!  No data after 10.5 seconds.\n");
        } else {
            // one or both of the descriptors have data
            //reading message from server
            int select_fd;
            for (select_fd = 0; select_fd <= nfds; select_fd++) {

                if (FD_ISSET(select_fd, &readfds) != 0) {
                    if (select_fd == s1) {

                        recv_len = 0;
                        recv_len = recv(s1, buf_msg, 34, 0);
                        if (recv_len < 0) {
                            perror("recv");
                            exit(1);
                        }
                        buf_msg[recv_len] = '\0';
                        printf("\nreceived from server = %s\n", buf_msg);
                        //send to neighbour

                        int sc3;
                        sc3 = connect(neighbour_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &neighbour, sizeof(neighbour));
                        if (sc3 < 0) {
                            perror("connect:");
                            exit(sc3);

                        }

                        str = malloc(1);
                        strcpy(str, buf_msg);
                        send_len = send(neighbour_socket, str, strlen(str), 0);
                        printf("\n send - len - s1  - %d\n", send_len);
                        if (send_len != strlen(str)) {
                            perror("send");
                            exit(1);
                        }
                        start_flag = 1;
                        //FD_CLR(s1, &readfds);

                        printf("\ncrossed server\n");

                    } else if (select_fd == s2) {

                        int list_len = sizeof incoming;
                        printf("\ninside client\n");
                        printf("\nWaiting for accept in S2\n");
                        if (p_flag == 0) {
                            p_flag = 1;
                            p = accept(s2, (struct sockaddr *) &incoming, &list_len);
                            printf("\nConnection accepted in S2\n");
                            if (p < 0) {
                                perror("bind:");
                                exit(rc);
                            }
                        }
                        nfds = MAX(nfds, p);
                        recv_len = 0;
                        buf_msg[recv_len] = '\0';
                        recv_len = recv(p, buf_msg, 34, 0);
                        if (recv_len < 0) {
                            perror("recv");
                            exit(1);
                        }
                        buf_msg[recv_len] = '\0';
                        printf("\nreceived from client = %s\n", buf_msg);
                        //send to neighbour

                        //if(start_id!=1){
                        int sc3;
                        sc3 = connect(neighbour_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &neighbour, sizeof(neighbour));
                        if (sc3 < 0) {
                            perror("connect:");
                            //exit(sc3);
                        }
                        //}

                        str = malloc(1);
                        strcpy(str, buf_msg);
                        send_len = send(neighbour_socket, str, strlen(str), 0);
                        printf("\n send - len - s2  - %d\n", send_len);
                        if (send_len != strlen(str)) {
                            perror("send");
                            exit(1);
                        }

                    } else if (select_fd == neighbour_socket) {

                        printf("\ncomes in\n");

                    } else if (select_fd == p && p != 0) {

                        int list_len = sizeof incoming;
                        printf("\ninside p\n");
                        recv_len = 0;
                        buf_msg[recv_len] = '\0';
                        printf("\nwaiting at recv in P\n");

                        recv_len = recv(p, buf_msg, 34, 0);

                        printf("\ncrossed at recv in P\n");
                        if (recv_len < 0) {
                            perror("recv");
                            exit(1);
                        }
                        buf_msg[recv_len] = '\0';
                        printf("\nreceived from client = %s\n", buf_msg);
                        //send to neighbour
                        str = malloc(1);
                        strcpy(str, buf_msg);
                        send_len = send(neighbour_socket, str, strlen(str), 0);
                        printf("\n send - len - neighbour - %d\n", send_len);
                        if (send_len != strlen(str)) {
                            perror("send");
                            exit(1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            FD_ZERO(&readfds);
            //FD_SET(neighbour_socket,&readfds);
            FD_SET(s1, &readfds);
            FD_SET(neighbour_socket, &readfds);

            if (p_flag == 1) {
                printf("\nsetting P\n");
                FD_SET(p, &readfds);
                FD_SET(s2, &readfds);

                p_flag = 0;
            } else {
                printf("\nNot setting P\n");
                FD_SET(s2, &readfds);
            }
        }
    }
    close(s1);
    close(s2);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter to `select` must be the maximum file descriptor *plus one*. As far as I can tell in that huge lump of code you posted, you forgot that "plus one".

Comment: That, and the fd_set needs to be re-initialized every time. In this code, it's not, it's done outside the loop, which is wrong

Comment: That is true, but the code posted might be doing that, there's some FD_ZEROs/FD_SETs near the end - given the indentation I have no idea if they are in the right place or not, or if they are sufficient.

Comment: So once a FD_ISSET becomes true and it executes one of the condition in the for loop that follows it, FD_SET has to be executed again. Again do i have to set all the FD's(s1,s2,p) into readfs ? and wait at select() again ?

I have one more related doubt, I noticed that select() can detect a connect() call, and it step from the select() statement to next statement. But it does not recognize a send() call, it still waits in the select() , even if there's a send() was executed on one of its sockets in readfds. Can you explain this behaviour ?

Comment: @Manoj, I think you're seeing what you're seeing because of the bugs that Mat and nos have found. `select(2)` is extensively used to determine when a remote peer has sent data using `send(2)` -- it is known to work. I suggest reading the `select_tut(2)` manpage, it has an excellent little example program.

Answer (score 3):

I believe [Mat has found the underlying problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7857990/c-sockets-blocked-on-select/7858006#7858006). But I think there is a much larger problem here:

```
int send_len;
char *str=malloc(1);
sprintf(str,"%d",peer_port);
printf("\nport-here=%s\n",str);
```

You have corrupted your heap with your `sprintf(3)` call. Maybe it isn't important data you've overwritten, and maybe `malloc(3)` won't ever actually allocate *one byte*, but that is a bad assumption to make. You need to allocate at least *six* bytes for a port number: five for the digits in `65535` and one for the trailing ASCII `NUL` `\0` byte.

```
  buf[recv_len] = '\0';
  char *temp_port;
  //printf("\n-%s\n",buf);
  if ( !strcmp("close", buf) )
        printf("%s",buf);
    //break;
  else{
    char *temp_buffer=malloc(1);
    char *id=malloc(100);
    char *pp=malloc(1);
    strcpy(temp_buffer,buf);
```

In the preceding selection, you have stored a `\0` into the end of `buf`, so you're presumably working with a string of some sort. But in a few lines, you allocate a single byte and then proceed to copy the contents of `buf` into that single byte. The ASCII `NUL` will use that byte entirely, leaving no space for the string you received. But `strcpy(3)` doesn't work that way -- it will copy the contents of `buf`, until that `'\0'` character, into the memory starting with your single byte. You've again destroyed your heap. But this time it can overwrite significantly more than five bytes -- and all under the control of the remote peer.

[Heap overflows are extremely dangerous](http://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/122.html). I found over 350 references to exploitable bugs in programs that derive directly from heap overflows in an old archive I have from the [Common Vulnerabilities and Exposures](http://cve.mitre.org/) project.

**Do not deploy this program on publicly-accessible machines until you have fixed these problems. It represents a significant security flaw.** Find every instance of `malloc(1)` and replace it with the *correct* amount of memory that must be allocated. Once you've done this, please run your program with `MALLOC_CHECK_=1` or under control of `valgrind(1)` to help you find further memory allocation problems.

Comment: Thank you. That was really useful. I better set out, reading on how to avoid Vulnerabilities in heap .

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using poll() instead of select()? It's easier to debug and scales elegantly to however many you need.

Comment: Well I wanted to work out with select() to understand it. However I will also try using poll(), once this is fixed . Thank you.